# How to detect what the content on the display is?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an app that rotates other apps. It uses an accessibility service so I have the ability to retrieve screen content.

Say I'm rotating a game called Geometry Dash to the portrait direction. Sometimes it will rotate correctly and look like this:

[image]

But other times it incorrectly appears like this:

[image]

Is it possible to detect when half the screen is black like in the second pic?

Perhaps using `AccessibilityNodeInfo` is the key since that class gives information about what's on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily be loading the content of the screen into a bitmap then you can split the bitmap in two parts.

Check if one of them is only black.

Comment: That's a clever idea :)